# Sorting words into categories in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have about 3,000 words and I would like to group them into about 20-50 different categories. My words are typical phrases you might find in company names. "Face", "Book", "Sales", "Force", for example.

The libraries I have been looking at so far are pandas and scikit-learn. I'm wondering if there is a machine-learning or deep-learning algorithm that would be well suited for this?

The topics I have been looking are Classification: identifying which category an object belongs to, and Dimensionality Reduction: reducing the random number of variables to consider.

When I search for putting words into categories on Google, it brings up kids puzzles such as "things you do with a pencil" - draw. Or "parts of a house" - yard, room.

Comment: Is it user inputs? i.e can the words be misspelled? like facebook -> facbeook? if so, you'd probably have to create a long list of all the words and misspelled words and loop them to be categorized..

Comment: I have the full list of words I want to use already, so it will not be user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for deep learning to work on this you would have to develop a large dataset, most likely manually. the largest natural language processing dataset was, in fact, created manually.
BUT even if you were able to find a dataset which a model could learn off. THEN a model such as gradient boosted trees would be one, amongst others, that would be well suited to multi-class classification like this. A classic library for this is xgboost.